# Simple Bootstrap buttons not showing variant colors in React

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

This is an out-of-the-box Create React App install, and I have only done two things:

1. `npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap`
2. Changed App.js as follows:

   ```
   import logo from './logo.svg';
   import './App.css';
   import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

   function App() {

     function buy() {
       alert('Clicked Buy');
     }
     function sell() {
       alert('Clicked Sell');
     }

     return (
       <div>
         <Button variant='success' onClick={buy}>
           Button1
         </Button>
         <Button variant='danger' onClick={sell}>
           Button2
         </Button>
       </div>

     );
   }

   export default App;
   ```

The buttons look the same as before I changed them from `<button>` to `<Button variant=...`:

[image]

Comment: *"an out-of-the-box React install"* - Create React App? Did you read https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#stylesheets?

Comment: yes - npx create-react-app

Comment: I read enough of it to install bootstrap I thought, guess I need to read the rest of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to import the css for the buttons to work

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to App.js, as per https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#stylesheets

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

The link statement is not required.

Results after adding css:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to a ES6 class definition:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import logo from './logo.svg';

import './App.css';
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.buy = this.buy.bind(this);
    this.sell= this.sell.bind(this);
  }

    function buy() {
    alert('Clicked Buy');
  }
  function sell() {
    alert('Clicked Sell');
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant='success' onClick={buy}>
        Button1
      </Button>
      <Button variant='danger' onClick={sell}>
        Button2
      </Button>
    </div>

  );
}

App()
```

Comment: That is absolutely *not* necessary, only the import of the CSS makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-bootstrap/

You need to add the dependencies in the `package.json` file (this is what `yarn add react-bootstrap bootstrap` will do).

Then `yarn`, to install the bootstrap-react node module.

Then you need to import of the bootstrap.css file.  Add that import line to the top of the index.js file.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

You can then see that it's imported when you inspect the html in devtools.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of npm install react-bootstrap , i did npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap as it says in the documentation.

Your code is right, but you should also add

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

in App.js